# Angular loop through object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following function which creates an array of objects inside `models`, however when I come to use `models` further down the app I'm unable to loop through it's contents to pull out data.

Every loop method I've tried so far containing a single `console.log()` message just prints out the message **once** message when `models` will contain **two** objects so I think the problem actually lies with the creation of `models`. If I create a promise and print out the value of `models.devices` when it's finished processing an empty array is returned.

Any ideas?

```
var d = devices.split(','),
    count = 0,
    models = {devices:[]};

angular.forEach(d, function (device, i) {

    var index = i;

    if (index <= 1) {

        var deviceName = device.replace(/ /g,"+").toLowerCase(),
            req = '?__url_path_param=' + deviceName;

        $http
            .get('/api/cheapest_by_name' + req)
            .success(function (obj) {
                models.devices.push(obj.device);
                count++;
            });

    }

});

$q.all(models).then(function (data) {
    apiDeal.multi(data, 3, 2);
});
```

Then... (in api-deal.factory.js)

```
function apiDeal($http, $rootScope) {

    return {

        multi: function (devices, limit, type) {

            console.log(devices); // equal to below image
            console.log(devices.devices); // equal to '[]'

        }

    }

}
```

[image: console.log(devices)]

I then need to loop through `devices` in `apiDeal.multi`

Comment: How are you waiting for your HTTP requests to complete? I see you're discarding the promises returned by $http that would allow you to do that.

Comment: Not quite sure what's not working for you. Is model undefined or something ? What does it mean *unable to loop through its contents* ?

Comment: @OmriAharon `models.devices` is blank or undefined

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen `$http.success ...`

Comment: So it appears you want `models` to be a global variable (also worth looking why, maybe you should place it in a service). Try defining it without `var`, you might be having scope issues. It's hard to tell just by the above code.

Comment: @OmriAharon I've updated my Q to give you a better understanding of how i'm using the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep an array of promises, which should replace the `models` you're using the `$q.all` on. It has to be an array of promises.

So change your code to this:

```
var d = devices.split(','),
    count = 0,
    models = {devices:[]},
    promises = [];

var promise = $http
            .get('/api/cheapest_by_name' + req)
            .success(function (obj) {
                models.devices.push(obj.device);
                count++;
            });

promises.push(promise);
```

And then, do:

```
$q.all(promises).then(function (data) {
    apiDeal.multi(data, 3, 2);
});
```

[Simple Fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13801/)

Comment: Note that `$q.all()` will be passing an array of all the promises' results into the `data` parameter of the function within its `then`. In which case, if possible, it may be better to just do `apiDeal.multi(models.devices, 3, 2);`, otherwise `data` will have to be sorted out before it can be passed to `apiDeal.multi()`.

Comment: @JcT Sounds about right. I'm guessing now that the OP is getting his data he'll be changing some code :)